# Set openlayers map height 100%

Tags: css, dictionary, openlayers

In openlayers when am trying to set map `height: 100%;` the map itself not displaying. When setting `height: 800px;` like this its showing white space in some resolution and scroller in some resolution.
So i want to do it like it can adjust height automatically. But `height: 100%;`
not helping.

```
<div id="map" style="height: 100%; width:100%; float:left; position: absolute;"> 
</div>
```

How do i solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple solution.

```
<div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position:fixed">
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  From experimentation it seems like only setting the map height to a value in pixels is effective.

Comment: It doesn't work for me too. It stretches the map over contauner. I ended up using: `$("#map").css("height", $(window).height() - 150); this.map.updateSize();`